# Displaying HTML File Content Saved on Firebase To A TextView

Tags: android, html, textview, firebase-storage, spannable

I'm downloading an html file from Firebase Storage and showing it on a TextView as a spannable. The problem is I get formatting info along with the text that's showing:

[image]

Scrolling underneath this formatting info, I get the real text correctly but without the original color "yellow," it's just black.

Here is the method that gets the file from Firebase Storage:

```
private fun fetchInfoData(){
    val database = Firebase.database
    val ref = database.getReference("aboutUs")
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
        override fun onDataChange(ds: DataSnapshot) {
            if(ds.exists()){
                val aboutUs = ds.getValue<AboutUs>() as AboutUs
                val storage = Firebase.storage
                val fileUrl = aboutUs.fileUrl
                fileUrl?.let {
                    val fileRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(aboutUs.fileUrl)
                    val ONE_MEGABYTE: Long = 1024 * 1024
                    fileRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener {
                        val html = it.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
                        Log.e("HTML IS: >>>>>", " HTML: " + html)
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            binding.tvAbout.text =  Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
                        }
                        else {
                            binding.tvAbout.text = Html.fromHtml(html)
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.e("<<< ERROR FILE REF >>>", "EXCEPTION: " + it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I get this html in the log:

p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 24.0px Arial; color: #ffff00}
        p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 24.0px Arial; color: #ffff00; min-height: 28.0px}
        p.p3 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 20.0px Arial; color: #ffff00}
        p.p4 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 20.0px Arial; color: #ffff00; min-height: 23.0px}
        p.p5 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; text-align: justify; font: 20.0px Arial; color: #ffff00}
        span.s1 {text-decoration: underline}
      
    
    
    **Introduction:**
    
...

I guess I only want the body without the head. How do we eliminate the head?